# Javascript: find english word in string

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

i want to find any english word (min 4 letters) in one string.

```
Eg: hello123fdwelcome => ["hello", "welcome"];
```

Could you suggest for me any solution or javascript lib to match english word.

Thanks

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @thefourtheye in put is: hello123fdwelcome; out put: ["hello", "welcome"]

Comment: This is not a question. This is a requirements list with a thinly veiled demand.

Comment: I guess you will have a source(for example a table) which contains all valid words to compare with, right?

Comment: @anna i need a lib which include a source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this list of words https://github.com/dwyl/english-words

```
var input = "hello123fdwelcome";
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile("words.txt", function(words) {
   var words = words.toString().split('\n').filter(function(word) {
       return word.length >= 4;
   });
   var output = [];
   words.forEach(word) {
       if (input.match(word)) {
           output.push(word);
       }
   });
   console.log(output);
});
```